# Выполнение Url запроса без ожидания ответа от сервера

Tags: url, php, запрос

Как выполнить на `php url` запрос без ожидания получения ответа от сервера?

Comment: вам нужно внутри php выполнить без ожидания? Под выполнением вы имеете в виду отправку POST и GET запросов?

Answer (score 3):

Люди никогда не научаться искать информацию. Ответом служит третья ссылка в гугл, если ввести заголовок данного вопроса.

Вот ответ: [Отправка POST-запросов с помощью php](http://www.web-junior.net/otpravka-post-zaprosov-s-pomoshhyu-php-chast-2/)